# Specify WHERE a LIKE clause can look

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to use a LIKE clause to help with a search function.
Depending on who is on the website the user will have a name and with that name I want to specify where in the database to look.

If I have a table like this: 
Name: stats

```
username - score - id
Erik     - 15    - 1     
John     - 10    - 2
John     - 12    - 3
Erik     - 15    - 4
Philip   - 13    - 5
Patrik   - 15    - 6
Patrik   - 17    - 7
Patrik   - 8     - 8
Erik     - 9     - 9
```

```
SELECT username, score, id, FROM stats WHERE id 
LIKE'%".search."%'
OR username LIKE'%".search."%'
OR score LIKE'%".search."%'
AND username = 'Erik';
```

what happens now is that it returns erik and patrik if i search for erik because rik get put into username search and if i put in 15 it will also return Erik and patriks values

Is there a way to overwrite this so when I put WHERE username = erik it will only use the Like clause on the rows that have that username value and not read through the whole table

Comment: You need to put parenthesis around your hierarchy that you want. `WHERE (id 
LIKE'%".search."%'
OR username LIKE'%".search."%'
OR score LIKE'%".search."%')
AND username = 'Erik'`

Answer (score 1):

Since my comment worked... Here is the solution suggested.

You need to put parenthesis around your hierarchy that you want.

```
SELECT username, score, id 
FROM stats 
WHERE (id LIKE'%".search."%'
OR username LIKE'%".search."%'
OR score LIKE'%".search."%')
AND username = 'Erik';
```